# How to replace argument name only for a particular class instantiation and not in other parts of code?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace, resharper

I use C# in Visual Studio 2017 (also have ReSharper 9) and came across the following problem:

I instantiate many classes like this:

```
new SystemMessage(SystemMessageType.Error, _internalId, "Request Failed: RequestAvailableScripts", e)
```

My goal is to replace the argument name `internalId` with `entityId`. I cannot do a global find/replace because `internalId` appears also elsewhere. I only want to replace the argument name within the constructor of `new SystemMessage(....)`. I am not familiar with Regular Expressions and have failed to understand how I can deal with the first argument of the constructor, `SystemMessageType.Error` as `Error` is only one possible value of the enum SystemMessageType`. I want to replace the argument name`_internalId`within **all**`new SystemMessage(....)` regardless of the first argument, passed into the class constructor.

Edit: To be clearer, the 1st, 3rd, and 4th argument in the constructor of that class differs, so regardless I want to replace the 2nd argument name but only in this particular class constructor not in other parts of the code.

Comment: Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/mNt4fs/2)?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Feel free to write a one-line answer and I can mark it complete.

Comment: Posted as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`(new SystemMessage\([^)]*?)(_internalId)`

Substitute with:

`$1entityId`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNt4fs/2)